# Terraform plan getting Error: Failed to decode resource from state

Tags: azure, terraform

Terraform initialize is working fine but when I do terraform plan getting below error.

Error: Failed to decode resource from state
│
│ Error decoding "azurerm_mssql_database.db" from previous state: unsupported attribute "extended_auditing_policy"

If I comment this particular resource then we start getting error for other resource.

Can some one please help me ?

Error: Failed to decode resource from state
│
│ Error decoding "azurerm_mssql_database.db" from previous state: unsupported attribute "extended_auditing_policy"

Comment: Hi @Surendra kumar G P can you provide the code that is used?

Comment: Are you referring to azurerm_mssql_database.db this resource code ?

Comment: What is TF code producing the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your Terraform state file contains resources that is applied  with newer version of terraform

Answer (score 0):

This issue typically arises due to compatibility problems between the Terraform state file and the current version of the AzureRM provider.

According to the discussion in [GitHub issue #7486](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/7486), support for the `extended_auditing_policy` setting was introduced in version `2.27.0` of the AzureRM provider. Therefore, you should ensure that you are using this version or later. If you are using an older version, you need to upgrade your AzureRM provider to a version that supports this feature.  [Latest version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs) is `3.90.0` and it is recommended to use the most up to date version available.

Here's what you should do to resolve the issue:

Update the AzureRM Provider Version: Specify the correct version of the AzureRM provider in your Terraform configuration file. Set the version to at least `2.27.0`, which is when the extended_auditing_policy was introduced.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = ">=  2.27.0"
}
```

Execute `terraform init -upgrade` to download and install the specified version of the AzureRM provider.

In any case, I recommend editing your question to provide the code that is producing the error as well as the definition of the provider you are using.